# javascript IF nested in a FOR loop not filtering results

Tags: javascript, canvas, if-statement, for-loop

I have a for loop that I am using to draw stuff from an array on to a canvas. The array holds a  bunch of variables.

These variables contain qualitative values like `firstName`, `lastName`, `team`, etc.

I know the variables are set up correctly because my other functions using them work fine. However, I have a `for` loop that is suppose to be drawing circles on the canvas only if team = 'blue' .

The problem is that it is recognizing them all as being 'blue' and drawing them all, when in fact only a few are 'blue' and other are 'red', 'green', etc.

here is the code:

```
            ctx.fillGroups = function(g){
                for ( var i=0; i<allSeating.length; ++i ){
                    if (allSeating[i.team]=g){
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.fillPerson(allSeating[i]);
                        //alert(allSeating[i.team]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

With the `alert()` active i can see that it thinks they are all blue.

I am guessing the issue lies with the line: `if (allSeating[i.team]=g)` but I cant seem to get it to work. Does the check for `allSeating[i.team]=g` need to happen elsewhere? But then why does it think that they are all `blue` team anyway?

**UPDATE: still not working here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/8ryvH/1/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`allSeating[i.team]=g` is not a check: it is an assignment statement.

What about `allSeating[i.team]==g` instead? (Am I missing something?)

The [Mozilla Developer's Network JavaScript Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) is a great resource for this sort of thing.

**Update:**

As said elsewhere, there's more here than `=` or `===`.

We noted in chat that `allSeating[i].team === g` is probably what you want to evaluate, but things still didn't add up.

I think the `seat` object is the problem, or rather the instantiation of it.

The definition has *eight* properties, but your instantiations have only *seven*.

Adding a value for the `fillStyle` property, as shown below, corrected the problem for me, and `allSeating[i].team === g` now evaluates true.

`var markTwain = new Seat(758, 180, 9,`**fillStyle**,`"Mark", "Twain", 6207, "red");`

Please let me know if you've got any more trouble.

Comment: you're my hero. When I had my initial test users in there I did have fillStyles defined, but when I loaded real users I forgot to add it. I can't thank you enough for spending the time you did looking into this. I really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `=` sets a variable ... use `allSeating[i.team]===g`

What's going on is that you are assigning `g` to `allSeating[i.team]` for every element in `allSeating`.  The `=` operator does not do the same thing in JavaScript as it does in VB or SQL -- in either of those languages `x = y` is an equivalency test or an assignment, depending on the context.  In JavaScript (and most other languages that I can think of), `=` is used only for assignment and `==` (and `===` in JavaScript) are used to test for equality.

`==` does type-casting to check equality while `===` does not.  (`"1" == 1 // true` but `"1" === 1 // false`)

Comment: And == checks coerced values whereas === checks type & value

Comment: @Anthony ... quite correct.  I've added that to my answer as well.

Comment: @Sean I had the same thought and tried both `==` and `===` both broke it completely =\

Comment: @tehaaron -- there are more issues with your code -- `i` is an integer, and it probably doesn't have the `.team` attribute.  Which means that you are continually setting the `undefined` key in your `allSeating` array to `g`'s value and then rendering the team member).  Change `allSeating[i.team]===g` to `allSeating[i]===g` and see what happens.

Comment: @Sean I tried that but nothing changed. If that was the reason, how come using just `=` would have yielded any results at all? With the alert it said the right team color and everything.

Comment: @tehaaron - assignment yields the value assigned ... so if `g` is "blue", then `(allSeating[i.team]=g) === "blue"` and `"blue"` is truthy, so the `if` statement runs.  When you say "with the alert it said the right team color and everything" ... you say in your question that "with the alert ... I can see that ... they are all blue".  Is every team member blue, or aren't they (and are they all claiming to be blue, or aren't they)?

Comment: @tehaaron let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1752/discussion-between-sean-vieira-and-tehaaron)

Comment: @SeanVieira I entered the chat but you must be away now. I have to go in about 5min but will check back regularly

Comment: I added a jsfiddle link if you're interested.